# Redirect page from one domain to another domain page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I seearched a little bit but seems like I cant find proper answer for my problem. I have 4 domains and I need to redirect 3 domains (and some of their pages) to new one.

`https://www.domain1.com/     to      https://www.domain4.com/music/domain1/`

`https://www.domain2.com/     to      https://www.domain4.com/music/domain2/`

`https://www.domain3.com/     to      https://www.domain4.com/music/domain3/`

and i need it for some pages also, for example:

`https://www.domain1.com/about.php    to  https://www.domain4.com/domain1/about/`

Can someone help me how to do this in htaccess?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello Aleksandar Simovic, sorry to bother here, could you please do check if my solution helped you here? You could let me know in comments section of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples. After placing these Rules into your .htaccess file, before testing make sure you clear your browser cache.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(domain[123])\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?$
REwriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain4.com/music/%1/ [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(domain[123])\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(about)\.php/?$
REwriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain4.com/%1/%2/ [NE,L]
```